# How to greet "Chinese New Year" to your Girlfriend

Tags: greetings, chinese-new-year

I want you to suggest me some very good greetings for Chinese New year which can make my girl friend think that I love her so much and I love her Only :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, Chinese New Year is not just between BF and GF, all Chinese celebrate Chinese New Year. I think this is the reason why someone voted down this question, but never mind, there is something much more important.

Since you asked. and there must be related with Chinese New Year, greetings, GF. I think you can say... ok, here we go.

honey, 新春快乐，我希望和你度过下一个甲午年。(please, only for the Chinese New Year of 2014)

In English: honey, happy new year, I want to spend my life with you forever.

Bro, this shows your respect of Chinese culture, shows your sincerity, shows you are willing to put effort to overcome anything to be with her, the exact result is much less important than your spirit.

PS: I'm not an expert in this field.

Comment: I've never heard 新春快乐, only 新年快乐 or 新年好.

Comment: @Ming let me explain, 新春 is the dedicated word only for lunar/Chinese new year. 新春 -> New Spring. you know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichun this is the start of spring in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term Chinese New Year is just around "start of spring", but if you say 新年 -> New Year, that is ambiguous, International or Chinese?

Comment: Yep sure sorry I wasn't contesting that, I'm just saying that I never hear anyone say it ^_^ I could have written my sentence more clearly actually.

Comment: @Ming 新春快乐 is also a very popular greeting.

Answer (score 1):

to your gf, you just say, 亲爱的，在新的一年我会更爱你呀。 Honey, I will love you more in the coming new year